# As a seasoned XCom player is it worth playing the Enemy Within Tutorial?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I've played XCOM Enemy Unknown up to Ironman Impossible level & know that to do well you need to skip the tutorial to get satellites launched early.

Starting XCom Enemy Within it without the tutorial it warns you that skipping the tutorial means you will miss a lot of story & game play critical information.

I've started on the tutorial and lost the 2 men on the 1st mission and don't have time for early satellites. Also I don't appear to have learn anything new from the tutorials so far.

Is there any reason to do the tutorial again for Enemy Within for experienced Enemy Unknown players?

Comment: There seem to be two tutorials - I skipped the main one but left the MELD one turned on. I'm guessing this is probably optimal for experienced players. But not having done the main tutorial I don't know whether it's identical to the old one or not...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do either the meld or the main tutorial. Meld is basically explained in game regardless of whether you do the tutorial, and the main tutorial is the same as it was before.

Comment: Many thanks. After doing the 2 tutorials I restarted and went through it again with no tutorials. You are correct, the only new thing is Meld and it's self-explanatory how that is used.

Answer (score -1):

I think going through meld tutorial is worth while because you can have free meld at the beginning, though the main tutorial is not.